# VideoJS Random Margin Firefox

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to use video.js to embed videos into a website I'm working on, but for some reason, in Firefox, there is a margin between the top of the container the video is in and the video itself.

The page can be found [here](http://world.penguinbait.com/sun/)

It works fine in Chrome, so I don't know why it won't work properly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.
Set the css for the container of the video to

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
```